# Keyboard wont navigate between input fields.

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ive tried every possibility to enable keyboard navigation between three input fields but nothing happens. Ive tried automatic, vertical and explicit. Ive checked the "Vizualise" option and see that the three input fields are connected. Ive set the first field to First Selected in the EventSystem. Help me Obi Wan!

[image]

Comment: And you're pressing the up and down arrow keys?

Comment: Yes! Also tab and everything else.